# Creating a 'decider-step-loop' with spring-java-config

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-java-config

I'm trying to port a spring-batch job, which is defined in xml to a java-config based job.
This is a snippet of my job-configuration-file:

```
<decision id="decision" decider="someDecider">
 <next on="continue" to="stepCont" />
 <next on="timeout" to="stepTimeout" />
 <end on="COMPLETED" />
</decision>

<step id="stepCont" next="stepReport">
  ... do something
</step>

<step id="stepReport" next="decision">
  ... create report
</step>

<step id="stepTimeout">
  ...
</step>
```

Is there a way to create such a loop with spring-java-config?

I started:

```
.get("myJob")
.start(someStepBefore())
.next(someDecider).on("timeout").to(stepTimeout())
.from(someDecider).on("continue").to(stepCont())
.from(someDecider).on("COMPLETED").end().build()
.build();
```

It must be like:

```
.get("myJob")
.start(someStepBefore())
.next(someDecider).on("timeout").to(stepTimeout())
.from(someDecider).on("continue").to(stepCont()).next(someDecider)...
.from(someDecider).on("COMPLETED").end().build()
.build();
```

My job is like the [loopFlowSample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/loopFlowSample.xml). How could I realize it without xml?

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
    FlowBuilder<Flow> flowBuilder = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("flow1");

    Flow flow = flowBuilder
        .start(importPersonStep)
        .next(loopDecider)
        .on("CONTINUE")
        .to(importPersonStep)
        .from(loopDecider)
        .on("COMPLETED")
        .end()
        .build();

    return jobs.get("importUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(flow)
            .end()
            .build();
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't achieve a loop. Based on what I have read, you'd have to dynamically create steps and add them in the flow to execute them repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I know really late but I didn't find a correct example and this question kept coming up in my google searches.

Here's a working example with the latest spring batch.

```
return jobs.get("myJob")
    .start(someStepBefore)           
    .next(stepReport)
    .next(someDecider).on("timeout").to(stepTimeout)
    .from(someDecider).on("continue").to(stepCont)
    .from(someDecider).on("COMPLETED").end() 
    .from(stepCont).next(someDecider).on("timeout").to(stepTimeout)
    .from(stepCont).from(someDecider).on("continue").to(stepCont)
    .from(stepCont).from(someDecider).on("COMPLETED").end()
    .end()
    .build();
```

Comment: Could you please guide here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65194027/duplicate-step-step2-detected-in-execution-of-job-job-if-either-step-fails ?

Comment: I am not sure, but its not working for me.