# Duplicate step [step2] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Spring Batch decider is going into forloop. I have below requirements.

If `Step1` execute, check decider() if `"NO"` then end Job, if `"Yes"` then execute `Step2`, if Step2 is COMPLETED then execute decider() f `"NO"` then end Job, if `"Yes"` then execute `Step3`.

Any guidance how can we configure in the batch?

```
2020-12-08 11:41:11.473  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
step1
2020-12-08 11:41:11.493  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step1] executed in 20ms
2020-12-08 11:41:11.508  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step2]
step2
2020-12-08 11:41:11.513  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step2] executed in 5ms
2020-12-08 11:41:11.568  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Duplicate step [step2] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2020-12-08 11:41:11.571  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step2]
step2
2020-12-08 11:41:11.577  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step2] executed in 6ms
2020-12-08 11:41:11.585  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Duplicate step [step2] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2020-12-08 11:41:11.589  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step2]
step2
2020-12-08 11:41:11.594  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step2] executed in 5ms
2020-12-08 11:41:11.601  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Duplicate step [step2] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2020-12-08 11:41:11.604  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step2]
step2
2020-12-08 11:41:11.608  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step2] executed in 3ms
2020-12-08 11:41:11.616  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Duplicate step [step2] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2020-12-08 11:41:11.618  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step2]
step2
2020-12-08 11:41:11.623  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step2] executed in 5ms
2020-12-08 11:41:11.630  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Duplicate step [step2] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2020-12-08 11:41:11.634  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step2]
step2
2020-12-08 11:41:11.638  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step2] executed in 4ms
2020-12-08 11:41:11.646  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Duplicate step [step2] detected in execution of job=[job]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
2020-12-08 11:41:11.648  INFO 16800 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step2]
step2
```

Java code

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return steps.get("step1")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("step1");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionDecider decider() {
        return (jobExecution, stepExecution) -> new FlowExecutionStatus("SUCCESS"); // or NO
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return steps.get("step2")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("step2");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step3() {
        return steps.get("step3")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("step3");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public Step step5() {
        return steps.get("step5")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("Step 5");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public Step step4() {
        return steps.get("step4")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("Step 4");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1())
                .next(decider())
                .from(decider()).on("SUCCESS").to(step2())
                .from(decider()).on("NO").end()
                .from(step2()).on("COMPLETED").to(decider())
                        .from(decider()).on("SUCCESS").to(step3())
                        .from(decider()).on("NO").end()
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Note - Due to security restriction, I'm unable to load Flow diagram from office workstation :(

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your flow definition. The `SUCCESS` outcome from the decider goes to two different steps:

```
.from(decider()).on("SUCCESS").to(step2())

...

.from(decider()).on("SUCCESS").to(step3())
```

Moreover, the transition definitions from `step2` are incomplete. You've only defined the transition from step2 on `COMPLETED`:

```
.from(step2()).on("COMPLETED").to(decider())
```

you should define the transition from `step2` for other cases as well.

Comment: Thanks, kindly post the changes in the code needed, that will help. Many thanks !